# Angular 2 FormBuilder with Select multiple

Tags: angular, formbuilder

How do I build the FormBuilder correctly on a select multiple?
It only works without being multiple.

I tried using FormArray, FormGroupName in HTML, however, all returning errors. And the examples I encounter are always non-tagged `<select multiple>`.

Could someone guide me?
Thanks.

.TS

```
this.detailFormGroup = this.fb.group({
   "id": [this.item.id],
    "name": [this.item.name, [Validators.required]],
    "categories": this.item.categories
});
```

.HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="detailFormGroup">
    <div>
       <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
       <select formControlName="categories" multiple>
         <option *ngFor="let item of categories" [value]="item.id">{{ item.categoryName }}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I need is that when I get the detailFormGroup.value I receive the object:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "name 1",
    categories: [
        {
           id: 5,
           categoryName: "name 5"
        },
        {
            id: 10,
            categoryName: "name 10"
        }
    ]
}
```

And of course, when I set the item object, the HTML controls are also selected with their items.

I'm getting wrong like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "name 1",
    categories: [ 5, 10 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an array of selected values. And in your HTML we can see `option [value]="item.id"`.

Just change this to `option [value]="item"`.